# I have a props with JSX.Element. How do I mock the same in the jest test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Im my react component, I have props like below

```
interface Props {
  errorMessage: JSX.Element;
  addCommentCancel: () => void;
  triggerAddComment: () => void;
  showAddCommentForm: boolean;
}
```

and in the test I'm invoking the component like below

```
const props =  {
  errorMessage: {},
  addCommentCancel: () => jest.fn(),
  triggerAddComment: () => jest.fn(),
  showAddCommentForm: true
};
let wrapper = mount(<IncidentCommentList {...props} />);
```

I get an error

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

How do I mock props element?

Comment: As its name says `JSX.Element` either stands for JSX element(e.g. `<span />`) or is a string. Maybe `null` also works but I'm not sure. Did not find `JSX.Element` declaration in React or DefinitelyTypes so not filling "official answer"

Answer (score 0):

```
const props =  {
  errorMessage: <div>errorMessage</div>,
  addCommentCancel: () => jest.fn(),
  triggerAddComment: () => jest.fn(),
  showAddCommentForm: true
};
let wrapper = mount(<IncidentCommentList {...props} />);
```

The above code fixed the issue.

Comment: What's the file extension your using for the test? I get an error with a .ts file.

Comment: The file extension is .tsx